# Problem with FindCycle function

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to count the cycles that are in the enclosed graph which  was generated using `MorphologicalGraph` ( follow this link to download the MM notebook https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PVoOK77NLPyfoWCWgQx8moG-pO94uSER ).

My idea was to use `FindCycle` function then use `Length` to count the elements in the `FinCycle` output/list . Unexpectedly, I got this:

```
{{3545 <-> 3540, 3540 <-> 3544, 3544 <-> 3545}}
```

Clearly there are more than 1 cycle in the graph. Whats going on here ?!

[image: Morphological Graph of a 2D maximum intensity projection of stem cell subcellular network]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented:

```
FindCycle[g]
  finds a cycle in the graph g.
```

It did.

Perhaps you wanted `FindCycle[g, Infinity, 3]`, for example, which would find three cycles. Using `All` will find all the cycles, and might take a long time.

Comment: Understood.Many thanks!